# How to select duplicate which is earlier in time in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to know how to efficiently select from duplicate rows determined to be duplicate rows based on a duplicated element in one column. Of the duplicate rows, I want to identify and select those that are earlier in time based on a date column. I solved this problem with the below code. I'm looking for a more efficient **base R** solution that does not involve a `for` loop.

```
# data required
data <- structure(list(var1 = c("11", "11", 
                                     "12", "12", "13", "13", 
                                     "14", "14", "15", "16"
), EndDate = structure(c(1588792540, 1588942766, 1589118458, 
                         1589059900, 1588669654, 1588979219, 1588876217, 1588786020, 1588506698, 
                         1588512011), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                     10L), class = "data.frame")

duplicate_var1 <- data$var1[duplicated(data$var1)] # save duplicate indices
data["identifier"] <- NA # create a new, empty column

# loop to determine where the duplicates are
for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]) { # for each row
  if (data$var1[i] %in% duplicate_var1 == TRUE) { 
    var1_locations <- which(data$var1 == data$var1[i]) 
    var1_location_2 <- setdiff(var1_locations, i) 
    if (data$EndDate[i] < data$EndDate[var1_location_2]) {
      data[i, "identifier"] <- 1
    } 
  } else {
    data[i, "identifier"] <- 1
  }
}

# save the reduced data
newdf <- data[!is.na(data["identifier"]), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not a Base R** solution, but I'll leave it here, in case it's useful to someone in the future.

```
library(data.table) # load data.table
setDT(data, key = "EndDate") # convert to data.table object and order by EndDate
```

As the data is ordered by EndDate (that was the key setting), take the first row of each group in which var1 is the same:

```
data[, .SD[1, ], by = var1]
```